# iMac Intel 21.5" EMC 2805 Looping chime on booting

Tags: hard-drive, imac, startup, ssd

I am in trouble with my imac. Let me tell our story;

My imac was too slow and I decided to change HDD with a SSD. If I just be changed HDD, There was no problem. But I want to clone my HDD to SSD hard drive.

- I cloned my HDD to SSD with follow this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Vxn4oJtFrg). I used Carbon Copy Cloner app for clone, and I did something with Multibeast like in video(I guess problem start this point, I wish I had not Multibeast).
- I changed HDD like [this link](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iMac+Intel+21.5-Inch+EMC+2805+Hard+Drive+Replacement/27886)
- Open my Imac and came a boot screen I never seen ago;
  [image: screen]
- I choose one but screen freezed, I waited for hours but there was no progress.
- And I close Imac use power button.
- Now my Imac looping chime on booting like [this macbook](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BSpikNzb0hQ)

Notes:

- If I unplug Screen cable, Chime sound come only one and fan running.
- I try thunderbolt output for display but not working.
- I try PRAM reset not working, I removed PRAM battery even but not working.
- I try reinstall macos with USB or direcly with HDD but not working.

I think Multibeast corrupted EFI Flash So I learned Multibeast using for Hackintosh after this incident.

How can I fix my Imac? If problem about with EFI Flash, How can I reinstall EFI on rom.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's a few things here that still aren't clear. For example, when you say that reinstalling macOS with USB or a HDD doesn't work, can you explain why? What actually happens when you try? Also, when you say *I try PRAM reset not working*, do you mean that you couldn't reset the PRAM, or that resetting it didn't fix the problem? And what happens if you try the "Boot Mac OS X from USB" option at bottom of the screen? Finally, it'd be good to know if you have: (1) access to any other Macs and, if so, which models, (2) a current backup of your data (I assume so if you used Carbon Copy Cloner).

Comment: 1- Imac can't boot from USB or HDD, I tried keyboard shortcuts but I can't interrupt boot loop.
2- I tried PRAM reset with keyboard combination and I also removed  PRAM battery for reset.
3- I am not want to save my data, I want to see apple logo on my Imac.

Comment: Okay, so, what happens if you power off your iMac and switch it back on and immediately hold down the Option+Command+R keys?

Comment: nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed my imac. Here is steps:

1. I bought a new EFI chip from https://macunlocks.com/
2. I changed chip on mainboard my imac. [image: chip on board]
3. Finally my mac was opened but lanuage was chinese and ask me efi password(new chip has no efi pass.)
4. Reset PRAM with CMD + Alt + P + R [how to reset PRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063)
5. Fixed! Imac living after 2 months later.

I founded solution and similar situation from [here](https://www.tonymacx86.com/threads/warning-report-booting-clover-on-a-real-mac-can-be-dangerous.229629/).